# What are the usages for ^ and how can I get more information on it?

Tags: clojure

found this on a blog : `(def x ^{:type ::my-class} {})`

apparently it adds meta data to a map

```
user=> (meta x)
{:type :user/my-class}
```

1. what else does `^` do ? does it have any other uses ? can it be used as a getter for meta data (not just to set meta data) ?
2. how can i find out information about some shortcuts in clojure ? like `^`, `'`, `` ` ``, `~`. is it possible to get that from the repl ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the Clojure reader, specifically the section on macro characters:

[The Reader](http://clojure.org/reader)

Edit: Metadata has [documentation](http://clojure.org/metadata) too :-)